# Largest possible dimension of the nullspace of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^3$, I would reason that the largest possible dimension for the nullspace is $4$ because the rank is always greater than or equal to $1$, and when the nullity is the number columns minus the rank:

$\operatorname{rank}(A)\geq 1$

$\operatorname{null}(A)=n-\operatorname{rank}(A)=
5-\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq 4$

The problem is that the answer book says the largest possible dimension is $5$. Am I wrong?

Comment: The rank of $A$ could be zero if $A=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why the rank must be $\ge1$. It can well be $0$, for the trivial linear map $f(x)=0$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$.